# file_exists /www/web/app/aaa/../../bbb.php return false and report the error of open_basedir restriction

Tags: php, linux, centos

`file_exists('/www/web/app/aaa/../../bbb.php')`
returns false.

The reported error is:

```
open_basedir restriction in effect.
```

But `open_basedir` params is OK and the file exists.
Why?

PHP5.6.9 and CentOS6.5

Answer (score 1):

[open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) is a configuration directive to limit files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself.

You will need to add the directory to your config via .htaccess or otherwise.

You can use
`php_admin_value open_basedir [directory]`